# Meaning of bullet sign in citation number

Tags: publications, citation-style

I'm reading [this research paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1359029411000549) and some of the citations are marked like this:

[29<sup>•</sup>] or [29<sup>•</sup>,[30],[31•]<sup>•</sup>,[32],[33],[34]]

The bullet points are in superscript, as well as nesting in the bracketing. There is no legend for this symbol in the paper; does it have a standardised meaning?

Comment: interesting way is also this:
[[3•], [4], 4]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By looking at more recent papers from the same journal, for example this https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359029415000369#bb0140
it looks like these are commented references.
With one dot • , they are referred as

> Of special interest because [...] It is where someone new to this area should start reading.

with two dots •• . they are referred as:

> Of outstanding interest because [...]

Interesting, although not of immediate understanding.

Comment: This is not *extremely* common, but I have come across it in different journals, so I would call it "semi-standardised" as per the OP's question.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree, although it may depends on the field. Do you have an idea how to read the nested reference [[3•], [4], 4]  ?

Comment: No, that one is strange. Looking at the html version, I see that the 3 and the first 4 are hyperlinked to the references - but the second 4 is not hyperlinked. As such, I would assume this is just a typo. (How one manages to introduce this kind of typo into what should presumably be an automatic BibTeX/LaTeX run is not clear to me.)